# Redirect to another domain without opening its app

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, ios

We are redirecting users to a website that has its own app.
The user would initially land and complete a form on our website, and then redirected to another website.

On Desktops everything is good - the destination website is being redirected on the browser as expected.
However on mobile - if the user has this app (Kayak) installed, it will open in the app instead of redirecting in the browser.

The redirection code we use:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1;url=https://www.kayak.com" />
```

I have tried replacing the HTML redirect with PHP redirect (via headers), and with JS redirect (via window.location.href), however both seemed to not make any difference.

How is it possible to make sure all users would remain in the browser?
We can use any type of redirect (HTML / PHP / JS) that would be helpful for this behavior.

Comment: There is probably nothing you can do about that from your end, because this is implemented within the website that you are redirecting to.